# Combining numerous strings into one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having the following problem.

My sample data looks as following:

`03D
03F
03G
03H
03I
04E
05D
05G
05H
06C
08D
08D (BEST)
08E
08E (BEST)
08F
08F (BEST)
08G
08G (BEST)
08H
08H (BEST)
08I
08I (BEST)
08J
08K
08k08K
08L
08L (BEST)`

I need to combine this data into one string that will looks like the following:

`03D;03F;03G;03H;03I;04E;05D;05G;05H;06C;08D;08D (BEST);08E;08E (BEST);08F;08F (BEST);08G;08G (BEST);08H;08H (BEST);08I;08I (BEST);08J;08K;08k08K;08L;08L (BEST);`

Note that there will always be data added to this table, therefore, I would need this to run accurately, to update a single field using the results of this.

The different values should be split with this operator `;`

The script I tried to achieve this is:

```
declare @loop   int
,       @Tempid int
,       @lookup varchar(max)

    declare @bin table
    (id  int identity primary key, bin varchar(100))

    insert into @bin (bin)
    select distinct
    cBinLocationName
    from    _btblBinLocation

    set @lookup =   ''
                begin
                    select @Loop = min(ID) FROM @bin
                    while @Loop IS NOT NULL
                        begin
                        set @Tempid =   (select id from @bin where id=@Loop)
                            set @lookup =   @lookup + (select bin FROM @bin where ID=@Tempid)+';'
                            select @Loop = min(ID) FROM @bin where ID>@Loop
                        end
                end
    select  @lookup
```

The problem is, my results is `''` the whole time.

Please help?

Comment: I don't think so, due to the data extract would be out of a SQL Table

Comment: Where is your data coming from if not a SQL table..?

Comment: It's coming out of a SQL Table, hence my code is `select distinct cBinLocationName from _btblBinLocation`

Comment: Don't be put off by the use of the `FOR XML` directive in the duplicate @Larnu linked, it's retrieving the data from a database table and concatenating it using a delimiter

Comment: Thanks Larnu, yes, your assistance helped. And thanks Diado, I've never used XML in this regard, I don't understand exactly how it works, but I managed to get it to work, I'll share the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by navigating to the link that Larnu posted in the comments.

I altered the answer in there to work for me and below is the script:

```
select top 1  stuff((select distinct cBinLocationName + ';'
            from _btblBINLocation
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as lookup
from _btblBINLocation
```

This does exactly what I want. With these results, I will be able to update a field based on this.

Thanks everyone.

The results looks like this:

[image]

Comment: No need for the TOP 1 or second FROM here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example without the need for XML and STUFF:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [TestData] NVARCHAR(200)
    );

DECLARE @Del CHAR(1) = ';';
DECLARE @Lookup NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [TestData]
                      )
VALUES ( '03D' )
     , ( '03F' )
     , ( '03G' )
     , ( '03H' )
     , ( '03I' )
     , ( '04E' )
     , ( '05D' )
     , ( '05G' )
     , ( '05H' )
     , ( '06C' )
     , ( '08D' )
     , ( '08D (BEST)' )
     , ( '08E' )
     , ( '08E (BEST)' )
     , ( '08F' )
     , ( '08F (BEST)' )
     , ( '08G' )
     , ( '08G (BEST)' )
     , ( '08H' )
     , ( '08H (BEST)' )
     , ( '08I' )
     , ( '08I (BEST)' )
     , ( '08J' )
     , ( '08K' )
     , ( '08k08K' )
     , ( '08L' )
     , ( '08L (BEST)' );

--puts the result set into @Lookup
SELECT @Lookup = @Lookup + [TestData] + @Del
FROM   @TestData;

--Remove the trailing delimiter
SET @Lookup = SUBSTRING(@Lookup, 1, LEN(@Lookup) - 1);

SELECT @Lookup;
```